# How to obtain single result from Hibernate SQLQuery instead of list

Tags: java, hibernate

This part is my Data Access Object function. This is where I execute the query and retrieve data from my SQL tables.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("//WORKING SQL STATMENT HERE");
query.setParameter("username", username);
query.setParameter("password", password);

query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Users.class));

query.addScalar("id");
query.addScalar("username");
query.addScalar("password");

Users user = (Users) query;
return user;
```

I am getting an error on my page:

> Status 500 - org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl cannot be cast to entity.Users

I think it is because casting

```
Users user = (Users) query;
```

is wrong.

I am trying to return an `User` object. All I know is `query.list();` but I don't what to return a users list.

**EDIT**

This is not the same object as query in javax.persistence.Query

Comment: This is a SQLQuery object not a Query object.

Comment: SQLQuery extends Query. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html You can use uniqueResult method.